# Is it a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have this set $B=A_1\cup A_2\cup A_3\cup \{(0,0)\}$ where

$A_1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, y>x^2\}\\A_2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, 0<y<x^2, x<0\}\\A_3=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2, 0<y<x^2,x>0\}$

If i suppose that $B$ is not connected then there exist two open, disjoint sets $U,V$ in $B$ such that $B=U\cup V$ and i suppose that $(0,0)\in U$

If i draw $B$ i see that any disc with center (0,0) has an nonempty intersection with $A_i, i=1,2,3.$

But i can't find contradiction with the fact that $U$ is open or with $U\cap V=\emptyset$

Thank you.

Comment: Let $X_k=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2:y=kx^2\}$. Is $X_k$ connected? is $B=\bigcup_{k\gt0,k\ne1}X_k$?

Comment: i really don't know

Comment: Are you familiar with "path-connected"? It implies "connected".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the union is connected and you have the correct idea. Since $(0,0) \in U$ and the $A_i$ are connected, and $A_i \cap U$ is nonempty, it must follow that $A_i \subset U$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$. Try to prove this. But then $V$ must be empty.

This is a special case of a more general statement: if $X$ is a topological space and $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a family of connected subspaces such that $\bigcap_i C_i$ is nonempty, then $\bigcup_iC_i$ is connected (try to prove this). You're basically applying this  to the sets $C_i=A_i\cup\{(0,0)\}$ for $1 \leq i \leq 3$, to show that the union is connected.

You can also prove directly that the desired set is path-connected.

Comment: to say that $A_i\subset U,$ $U$ must be open and closed is U closed ?

Comment: $A_i \subset U$ because otherwise $A_i \cap U$ and $A_i \cap V$ would both be nonempty, which would contradict the connectedness of $A_i$.

Comment: why $A_i\cap V$ is nonempty we juste have that $A_i\cap U$ is nonempty

Comment: $B=U \cup V$. Therefore $A_i \subset U \cup V$ for each $1 \leq i \leq 3$. Therefore if $A_i \not\subset U$ then $A_i \cap V$ must be nonempty.

Answer (score 0):

Your goal is to show that $V = \emptyset$.

For all $i=1,2,3$ you have
$$A_i = (A_i \cap U)\cup(A_i \cap V)$$
with $A_i \cap U \neq \emptyset$ and $A_i \cap U, A_i \cap V$ open. Since $A_i$ is connected, you have $A_i \cap V = \emptyset$.

Finally, $V = (A_1 \cap V) \cup (A_2 \cap V) \cup (A_3 \cap V) \cup (\{ 0\} \cap V) = \emptyset$.

Comment: Please why $A_i\cap V=\emptyset$ and $V = (A_1 \cap V) \cup (A_2 \cap V) \cup (A_3 \cap V) \cup (\{ 0\} \cap V) = \emptyset$ ?

Comment: Because $A_i$ is connected, and $A_i = (A_I \cap U) \cup (A_i \cap V)$, which are disjoint and open. As for the second, write $V= V \cap B = V \cap (A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \{0 \})$ and distribute.

Comment: why we can say that $A_i = (A_i \cap U)\cup(A_i \cap V)$ ?

Answer (score 0):

For all elements $(x,y)\in B$ there is path that connects $(x,y)$ and $(0,0)$.

This implies that $B$ is path-connected, and consequently is connected.

---

In the context of your question: let it be that $B=U\cup V$ where $U,V$ are disjoint, open and non-empty.

Let $u\in U$ and let $v\in V$ and let $p:[0,1]\rightarrow B$ be a path with $p(0)=u$ and $p(1)=v$.

Then $[0,1]=p^{-1}(U)\cup p^{-1}(V)$ where $p^{-1}(U)$ and $p^{-1}(V)$ are open, disjoint and non-empty.

This however contradicts that $[0,1]$ is connected.

Comment: Why $[0,1]=p^{-1}(U)\cup p^{-1}(V)$ ?

Comment: $[0,1]=p^{-1}(B)=p^{-1}(U\cup V)=p^{-1}(U)\cup p^{-1}(V)$

Comment: this is always true or juste because U and V are disjoint ?

Comment: It is always true. Also if $U$ and $V$ are not disjoint.

Comment: i want to ask you an auther question if i suppose that $(0,0)\in U$ and i found finelly that $A_i \subset U$ then all $B\subset U$ and then V mest be empty right ? and if i say that U is open in B then we have also that U is closed in B because $U=C_{B} V$

Comment: Yes, then $V$ is empty. If you are saying that $U$ is open in $B$ then you are implicitly saying that $U\subset B$. If next to that $B\subset U$ then we have $B=U$. And set $B$ is also closed in $B$.

Answer (score 0):

It is path-connected, hence connected.

*Sketch:*

Indeed, for any point $M_i\in A_i\enspace (i\in \{2,3\}$, consider the arc $\gamma_M$ of the parabola that passes through and is tangent to the $x$-axis at $O$, and for a point $M$ in $A_1$, the line segment $[MO]$. Any points $M, N\in B$ can always be connected by the union of two of these paths.